# alternatives to "Having" in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I'm in the DB classes, and I have to understand and show that it is possible to get the results of `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` without using themselves. I searched for alternatives for those 2 commands, but I didn't understand anything.

Can someone give me examples?

```
select n_name 
from(
select n_name, count( distinct c_custkey) AS aa 
from nation AS n INNER JOIN customer AS c ON c.c_nationkey=n.n_nationkey

GROUP BY n_name 
HAVING aa=(select MAX(cc) 
from ( select n_name, count(distinct c_custkey) AS cc 
from nation AS n 
INNER JOIN customer AS c ON c.c_nationkey=n.n_nationkey
    GROUP BY n_name
    ORDER BY n_name))
    ORDER BY n_name);
```

Comment: You'll have to elaborate. Using `group by` or `having` is not syntactic sugar at all. The replacements for them are only more complicated. The query you posted don't look useful to me. Mostly you'd be using lots of `select distinct` and correlated subqueries I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you can use `WITH` to combine duplicate parts of the request and do the check through `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
WITH
  base_data AS (
    SELECT n_name, COUNT(DISTINCT c_custkey) AS count
    FROM nation AS n INNER JOIN customer AS c ON c.c_nationkey=n.n_nationkey
    GROUP BY n_name
  )

SELECT n_name
FROM
  base_data
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(count) AS max_count
    FROM base_data
  ) AS max_data ON base_data.count = max_data.max_count
ORDER BY n_name
```